# HTML is there a way to limit the year to 4 digits in date input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I am developing a django app.
I have date input in my form:

```
<input type="date" name="date_of_birth" max="03.11.2020" max-length="8" pattern="[0-3][0-9].[01][0-9].[0-9]{4}" class="dateinput form-control" required id="id_date_of_birth">
```

It allows to enter the date with the year having 6 digits, but I wish it was only possible to enter 4.
I also tried to write a simple script:

```
$(function() {
        $('#id_date_of_birth').change(function() {
            var date = $(this).val();
            console.log(date, 'change')
        });
    });
```

but it only starts when I change the year.
I would like the numbers to loop on 4 digits instead of 6.
Can someone give me a hint how to limit the year to only 4 digits?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (with at least one of your attempts _"I tried max, max-length attribute with pattern."_)

Comment: The format for `max` (and `min`) is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @Andreas Ok, my mistake. Thanks.
But I still want the digits of the year to shift on 4 positions, not 6.

Comment: If the type is `datetime-local`, the format is [`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#max). (e.g. `max="9999-12-31T23:59"`)

Answer (score 5):

I like the suggestion of using the attribute max.  Just set the max="9999-12-31" in your input date type field and the year portion will be limited to 4 digits instead of 8.  This solved my problem.

Comment: As [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660946/html-is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-year-to-4-digits-in-date-input#comment114329994_64661084](commented below) it still allows more than 4 digits for year even if you use max. It can be validated in the [https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min_date](w3schools link) posted in same post.

Answer (score 2):

Add the attribute `max` to fix this. Browsers dont limit the year field to four digits by default.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min_date

Comment: It still allows to enter 6 digits. I know that the backend will return the error if year is too long. But I want it not to be possible on the frontend either.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in the sense that the 'max' attribute will limit the year (at least in Chrome), but the date format is incorrect.

Here's the correct date format

```
<input type="datetime-local" max="9999-12-31T23:59" name="my-date"/>
```